# When inserting images into posts auto add a wrapping div

Tags: images

When I add images to a post via the TinyMCE editor I’d like WP to add a wrapping div around the `<img>` tag like `<div class="img-wrapper"><img src="url-to-image" alt="image" /></div>`. Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a better idea, if you filter the output, the `the_content` and add the div on all images. It is better for feature, if you will remove this markup, it is not inside the database.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'fb_add_div_to_img' );
function ( $content ) {

    // find img and add markup
    return $content;
}
```

To find and replace the img in content use a regex, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

If you use the regex `preg_match_all( '/\<img [^>]*src=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>/', $content, $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);` then you get a array. Inside this array you find the img tag with all values, `$arr[0]`. Enhance this var with your markup and return to the var `$content`. Also here [a example](http://pastebin.com/PJ9S4zWe) from the web. Additional hint for a regex tester, there I like: [Regex Test Tool](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php)

But it is also possible to add markup on insert images in the editor:

```
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'fb_give_linked_images_class', 10, 8 );
function fb_give_linked_images_class( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ){

    $html; //contains the string you need to edit, you might want to consider to rebuild the complete string.

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an advice how to add the regex to the function? Never heard of that before.

Comment: Maybe the enhancement help you; current I dont on a machine to test regex and source.